# Rendering based on layer overlap qgis?

Tags: qgis, style

I'm a little new to this, is there a way to have features on a layer render only if they overlap with features on another layer?

I have roads of a city, and different areas in the city, and I'd like to only render roads that are entirely within the bounds of the city. I guess that means using a rule-based render on the features in the road layer, I just don't know the syntax of the condition "Overlaps with city layer."

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible. You need to have the **refFunctions** plugin installed and enabled by going to the menubar:

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
```

Select the **Rule-based** style of your desired layer and use an expression like the following (*note that single quotation marks for the field name*):

```
geomoverlaps( 'other_layer_name', 'any_field_name' )
```

---

**Example:**

1. Two example layers, "Layer_2" has a couple of polygons which overlaps the two polygons in "Layer_1":

   [image: Layers]
2. Now we set the **rules** for "Layer_2" using the expression above:

   [image: Rule-based style]
3. Result!

   [image: Results]