# Spatial Relationship in QGIS

Tags: qgis, relationship-class

I'd like to add a layer in QGIS, not just filtered by attribute, but using a spatial relationship.

For example, visualize only river features that are within the state of São Paulo, Brazil.

How can I do this in QGIS without having to create a new shapefile and cut that data to the state?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Rendering based on layer overlap qgis?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200860/rendering-based-on-layer-overlap-qgis)

Comment: You can use a ruled-based style and as a rule use the following:
within(  $geometry,   geometry( get_feature( 'State_Layer_name','State_name_attribute','Sao Paulo')))