# Creating Direction data in QGIS between two layers?

Tags: qgis, table, direction

Can I do it in Qgis, that there are two layers, a target layer and an input layer, and I ascertain with an algorithm so that the closest points on the input layer are on the target layer in what direction they are?

Measured in degrees, with designation east, west, north, south, north east, south east, northwest, southwest?

Creating a table that contains this data?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 6):

Not that long ago, I did something similar using two point layers: one containing the **source**; the other containing **destinations**.

Example layers:

[image: Example layers]

---

What I did was:

1. Use the **Distance to nearest hub** algorithm with the following parameters to create a line layer showing the nearest destination point to the source point:

   [image: Distance to nearest hub]

   You can find the tool from:

   ```
   Processing Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector analysis tools > Distance to nearest hub
   ```

---

2. Create a **real** field (e.g. "Direction") on the resulting line layer using the **Field Calculator** to calculate the *direction* of the lines using the expression below ([as described in this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/how-to-add-direction-and-distance-to-attribute-table)):

   ```
   (atan((xat(-1)-xat(0))/(yat(-1)-yat(0)))) * 180/3.14159
   + (180 *(((yat(-1)-yat(0)) < 0) + (((xat(-1)-xat(0)) < 0 
   AND (yat(-1) - yat(0)) >0)*2)))
   ```

   [image: Field calculator direction]

---

3. Create a **string** field (e.g. "Principal") in the same line layer to calculate the principal direction of the line (i.e. north, north-east etc) using the expression below:

   ```
   CASE
   WHEN "Direction" >= 348.75 OR "Direction" < 33.75 THEN 'N'
   WHEN "Direction" >= 33.75 AND "Direction" < 78.75 THEN 'NE'
   WHEN "Direction" >= 78.75 AND "Direction" < 123.75 THEN 'E'
   WHEN "Direction" >= 123.75 AND "Direction" < 168.75 THEN 'SE'
   WHEN "Direction" >= 168.75 AND "Direction" < 213.75 THEN 'S'
   WHEN "Direction" >= 213.75 AND "Direction" < 258.75 THEN 'SW'
   WHEN "Direction" >= 258.75 AND "Direction" < 303.75 THEN 'W'
   WHEN "Direction" >= 303.75 AND "Direction" < 348.75 THEN 'NW'
   END
   ```

   [image: Field Calculator principal]

---

4. You should (hopefully) have the degree values and their respective principal directions in the *Attribute Table*. You could then, if you wanted, add some style and labelling to the line layer to showcase the attributes.

   I used an arrow style:

   [image: Arrow style]

   And labelled it:

   [image: label]

   To get this result:

   [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

Probably [refFunctions](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin is useful. It will give you additional functionalities in the `Field Calculator`.
When installation of refFunctions is done, open the attribute table of your `input_layer`.  Create 3 new fields in the following order:

Field *[pt]*   ......Text(String) length=40

```
geomnearest('target_layer', '$geometry')
```

Field *[az]*   ......Decimal number (real) length=12.8

```
degrees(azimuth($geometry,  geom_from_wkt("pt")))
```

Field *[dir]* ......Text(String) length=10

```
CASE 
WHEN  0 <= "az" AND "az" <= 45 THEN 'N'
WHEN 45 <  "az" AND "az" <= 135 THEN 'E'
WHEN 135 < "az" AND "az" <= 225 THEN 'S'
ELSE 'W'
END
```

Then you will get something like below:

[image]

Sorry I was lazy and skipped NE, SE, SW, NW but you will get an idea.

Comment: Well that's awfully a lot easier than what I had done in the past! Nicely done :)

Comment: Thanks @Joseph! To be 100% honest I learned about this plugin from your answer to this question. [Rendering based on layer overlap qgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200860/rendering-based-on-layer-overlap-qgis)

Comment: Oh,... my `CASE WHEN` part for dir field is definitely wrong!  Stupid me :/